# java text to 2d array but prints IndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java

data in txt file looks

```
1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5
1.1, 3.3, 5.5, 7.7, 9.9
1, 4.4, 5, 100, 5050
1010, 2, 3, 4, 55
```

What I am trying to do is to create 2-D array for this data sets

2-D array should look like this:

```
1.1   2.2   3.3   4.4   5.5
1.1   3.3   5.5   7.7   9.9
...
...
1010   2   3   4   55
```

**Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class QuestionB
{
    public QuestionB(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            readFile(fileName);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        QuestionB questionB = new QuestionB("wine.data");


    }

    public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        String matrix[][] = new String[178][13];

        int test = 1;
        while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)
        {
            String values[] = line.split(",");  

            for(String str : values)
            {
                //System.out.println("test: " + test++);
                //System.out.println(str);
                matrix[x][y] = str;

                //System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");

                y = y + 1;
            }

            x = x + 1;

            //System.out.println("");

        }
    }
}
```

When I printed str, it prints all values correctly, but when I put str into matrix[x][y] it gives indexoutofbound error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
    at QuestionB.readFile(QuestionB.java:48)
    at QuestionB.<init>(QuestionB.java:12)
    at QuestionB.main(QuestionB.java:21)
```

Comment: Obviously your program will fail, if `line.split(",")` returns more than 13 elements or if you have more than 178 input lines. If you don't know the size of your inputs in advance you should try to use `ArrayList` instead of fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `y` for each inner loop

```
while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        y = 0;   //RESET y

        String values[] = line.split(",");  
        for(String str : values)
        {
            matrix[x][y] = str;
            y = y + 1;
        }
        x = x + 1;
    }
```

NOTE : as `dpr` said, this will still fail if your file is incorrect (more than 13 element per line or more than 178 line. An `ArrayList` is better for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not want to use Collection like ArrayList than Jagged Array is best option for you.

```
String matrix[][] = new String[max][];
```

where max is variable and assign max to a value that it can store total rows.

and also you need to assign y=0, each time when next line is read from file i.e in start of while loop.

Comment: You need to read the file once to get the value of `max` and you still need to instanciate each "sub array", you are not mentionning this ... this is incomplete.

Comment: I just suggest for max value that is any constant that store total file rows.because array is fixed size.and Eric don't want to use ArrayList

Comment: Well, he already use a constant of `178` ... but this is not safer. But for your `Jagged Array`, you are still missing important part to have a working code... Right now, you will have a NPE. And he never said he didn't want to use it but that not the point here.

Comment: why NPE..??file has fixed number of rows.so i suggest max with maximum size if rows not fixed than List is best.(if he want to use List).

Comment: Because `new String[max][]` create an array of `max` cells but don't create the sub-array. You don't set a size for them. So you will need to create each array separatly before use.